# Sort list of single item dictionaries?

Tags: python

I have a list with individual items as dictionaries which might have different keys. I want to sort them based on the values. E.g.

Lets say,

```
unsorted_list = [{'a': 23}, {'b': 34}, {'c': 2}]
```

After sort, (descending)

```
sorted_list = [{'b': 34}, {'a': 23}, {'c': 2}]
```

Please let me how to do it in python

Comment: Folks: This is not a duplicate of any of those. The question is about sorting a list that contains dictionaries (by the contents of the dictionaries).

Comment: This question is slightly different in the case that here each item in the list is a dict. Also keys are different for different dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to sort the elements according to the dict values (there is only one value anyway), in reverse:

```
unsorted_list = [{'a': 23}, {'b': 34}, {'c': 2}]

sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key = lambda d : list(d.values()), reverse=True)
```

result:

```
[{'b': 34}, {'a': 23}, {'c': 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
unsorted_list = [{'a': 23}, {'b': 34}, {'c': 2}]
final_data = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x:x.values()[0])[::-1]
```

Output:

```
[{'b': 34}, {'a': 23}, {'c': 2}]
```

Comment: You should pass the `reverse=True` keyword to `sorted()` instead of the having the `[::-1]` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]*-1)
```

or

```
sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0], reverse=True)
```